# JBjson Build Error with strotoull

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I am receiving the following error when building a project with the newest project JBJson.  Reason?

```
Unexpected '@' in program

JBJsonStreamParser.m

delegate parser:self foundNumber: @(strtoull(token, NULL, 10))];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@( <expression> )
```

is a "boxed expression" and is a relatively new feature of Objective-C.
(See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html for more information.)

```
@(strtoull(token, NULL, 10))
```

is equivalent to

```
[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:strtoull(token, NULL, 10)]
```

If you get a compiler error,
then perhaps you are using gcc and not clang, or your compiler version is too old.

Comment: @MikeFlynn: Compare https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/: You need LLVM Compiler 4.0.

Comment: Would LVVM GCC 4.2 work?  I changed the compiler and now getting more errors.

Comment: @MikeFlynn: Probably not, but I did not test every version :-) I think you have to upgrade to Xcode 4.4 at least, and use Clang instead of gcc.